# Mock with submodules for ReadTheDocs

Tags: python, mocking, read-the-docs

I'm trying to document a Python project with ReadTheDocs. Initially, the build process would die when it got to:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
```

I've read the [rtd faq](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules) and used mock for the osgeo module that was giving me trouble. Now the build process makes it past that import but chokes on:

```
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
```

With this rather unhelpful error:

```
RuntimeError: sys.path must be a list of directory names
```

I'm completely new to using mock but I think the problem is that `osgeo` is a mock module and therefore does not have the submodule `gdalconst`. How do I get around that? Is there a way to mock the submodule too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit late… but I ran across this looking for a solution (using nested modules with `mock`). I've mocked module and submodules like this:

```
MOCK_MODULES = ['dbs', 'dbs.apis', 'dbs.apis.dbsClient']
sys.modules.update((mod_name, Mock()) for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES)
```

where the order mattered. Hope this helps anyone else looking to solve this.